# Laravel uploaded image fires a 404 Not Found error

Tags: file-upload, laravel-5.3

I've written a Laravel 5.3 app that uploads an image and saves its details to the database. When I used it on localhost, everything worked fine. As soon as I uploaded it to Forge, all images uploaded via the app return a 404 code instead of displaying the image.

Some details:

- The new files are uploaded correctly. I can access them via console and ls -l the files.
- The new files have the same permissions and owner as the files I have uploaded via local and then pushed to the server. The old files (those pushed) are showing. The new files (those newly uploaded) are giving 404.
- The new files and the old files have an identical URL structure. That is, they both go to /storage/uploads/file_name.jpg

The upload code:

```
if($image = $request->file('image')) {
        $file_data = [];
        $file_data['path'] = $image->store('uploads', 'public');
        $file_details = pathinfo($file_data['path']);
        $file_data['url'] = 'uploads/';
        $file_data['filename'] = $file_details['filename'];
        $file_data['extension'] = $file_details['extension'];
        $file_data['is_image'] = 1;

        $file = new File($file_data);
        $file->save();
        $data['image'] = $file->id;
    }
```

Help, please!

Comment: confront the same problem, don't know why...